# Solve the following Defferntial Equation $xy^2y'=\frac{x^3}{\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}+y^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following:
$$xy^2y'=\frac{x^3}{\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}+y^3$$
I dont know if I can separate variables here because of the $\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: I suggest variation of parameter method: by using substitution $y=xv$.

Comment: ok, so I set $y=zx \rightarrow y`=z`x+z$ I need to get to a equation with $z$ and $x$?

Comment: You can make it read $y'=(\frac{y}{x})^{-2}{\mathrm {ln}(\frac{y}{x})}^{-1}+\frac{y}{x}$, but it's a hard nut in any case.

Comment: @NickKidman actually its a good way, I get to $$z`x+z=z^{-2} \cdot \frac{1}{ln(z)}+z$$

Comment: @OfirAttia: What I mean by "hard nut" is that I typed the differential equation into the Mathematica software and the result involves [ProductLog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html), i.e. there is no simple answer in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: It is a type of first-order homogeneous equation, that is, it is of the form, $y'=f(\frac{y}{x})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

Put $y=vx$. This gives us $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=v+x\cdot\dfrac{dv}{dx}$$.

So, $$x^3\ v^2\ \big(v+x\ \dfrac{dv}{dx}\big)=x^3\big(\dfrac{1}{\ln(v)}+v^3\big)$$

Simplifying, We get $$\dfrac{x^3\big(x\ v^2\ln(v)\dfrac{dv}{dx} -1\big) }{\ln(v)}=0$$

$$ x\ v^2\ln(v)\dfrac{dv}{dx} -1=0 $$  This is variable separable.

Further simplification gives us: $$\ln(v)\cdot v^2 dv=\dfrac1x dx $$ Integrate and substitute for $y$.

You're done.